# Mysql select query data joining

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Here is my first query

```
SELECT 
    tax_productid,
    CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(tax_code SEPARATOR " "), " ", sum(tax_iva), "%") AS tax
FROM tb_tax t group by tax_productid order by tax_productid, prd_type desc;
```

which returns a proper tax applied on product (multiple tax type may applied on single product)

output data like.

```
tax_productid       tax
=========================
1                   tax1 tax2 10%
2                   tax1 tax2 20%
3                   tax1 tax2 30%
```

now there is a another table `product` and query is like

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY productName;
```

return 10 product records.

I want to get product wise tax list but if there is no tax show null

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, 
    CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(tax_code SEPARATOR " "), " ", sum(tax_iva), "%") AS tax 
FROM 
    product t1, tb_tax t2 
WHERE
    t2.tax_product = t1.id;
```

this query returns only 3 rows. I want to list all products if table `tb_tax` has no entry for product then return null. so how can I acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is using `INNER JOIN`, you should use `LEFT JOIN` for this case:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, 
    t2.tax    
FROM 
    product t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      tax_productid,
      CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(tax_code SEPARATOR " "), " ", sum(tax_iva), "%") AS tax
    FROM tb_tax 
    GROUP BY tax_productid 
) t2 ON t2.tax_productid = t1.id
```

Comment: Not working :(  As you can see in first query I am using `group_concat()` and `sum()` which may requires group by clause.

this query give a single row with concating all `tb_tax` data in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(tax_code SEPARATOR " "), " ", sum(tax_iva), "%") AS tax 
FROM 
    product t1
LEFT JOIN 
    tb_tax t2
ON 
    t2.tax_product = t1.id;
```